# when call router.post method from url get error 404 not found in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have got a problem with Express, I am trying to use the app.post() function but it's not working and I don't know why...

Even though I have included the bodyParser()...

It returns 404 page not found error

```
var express = require('express');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var router = express.Router();

router.post("/hello",(req, res) => {
        res.send('POST CALL');
    });

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/nicky', function (err, client) {
        if (err) throw err

        var db = client.db('nicky')

        db.collection('student').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err
            res.send(JSON.stringify(result));
        })
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

GET is working properly, but POST is not.

Comment: Hi Nicky Vai, did you try to call from postman?

Comment: Can You provide snippet of your code error if have any. I think you should make a post request while accessing post router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how rest of your code looks, but I have copied your provided snippet and it works this way:

*express-post.js:*

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/bar/hello
router.post("/hello",(req, res) => {
    res.send('It is POST');
});

// curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/bar/hi
router.get('/hi', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('It is GET');
});

module.exports = router;
```

*express-post-server.js:*

```
const express = require('express');
const bar = require('./express-post');
const app = express();

// curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/foo
app.get('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('This is foo GET!');
});

// register
app.use('/bar', bar);

app.listen(3000);
```

For complete running example clone [node-cheat](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/commit/f1898c40ba76058d994cbe29159cbf5c1b99c983) and run node express-post.

Comment: GET / 404 280.007 ms - 1112
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 6.553 ms - -
GET /hi 200 1.588 ms - 9
GET /hello 404 19.140 ms - 1112
GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 0.564 ms - not work

Comment: /hello is a POST not GET, so it is giving a valid error, 404 means not found. You can use postman or curl as I have provided instructions in code snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you haven't required and initialized body-parser!
Just confirm once if you have included this:

```
  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  // support parsing of application/json type post data
  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  //support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot to use
 app.use('/',require('import route here'));
in main app.